# 2-colorable graphs

Tags: graph-theory

A graph is 2-colorable if its vertices can be colored with 2 colors in such a way that no edge exists between two vertices of the same color.

Show that for an infinite graph G, if every finite subgraph of G is 2-colorable, then G is also 2-colorable.

Do I now have to prove the compactness theorem or what exactly am I to prove?
An idea I had was to do an induction proof where I show that if a graph containing k verticals is 2-colorable then a graph with k+1 verticals is 2-colorable and as such the graph containing k verticals would be a subgraph of G containing k+1 verticals.

Comment: You should *use* the compactness theorem to prove the given statement about infinite graphs.

Comment: That induction doesn't necessarily work, because you may not always be able to extend from any 2-coloring on $n$ vertices to that of a 2-coloring on $n+1$ vertices,  even though we know there exists a valid 2-coloring on $n+1$ vertices (the converse is obvious though).

Comment: Are you familiar with Konig's lemma? If so, apply it to this scenario.